# Parsing twitter api JSON in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, twitter

I am using Twitter-Kit/Fabric to get a response from the twitter api. It returns a JSON of the following format - https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets

My query is - `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=""&geocode=lat,long,radius&count=15`

I need to extract the text and the coordinates from the JSON to plot those tweets on a map.

What am I doing wrong with the following code - ?

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.sendTwitterRequest(request) {
                    (response, data, connectionError) -> Void in
        if (connectionError == nil) {
            var jsonError : NSError?
            let parsedResult  =
            NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,
                            options: nil,
                            error: &jsonError) as NSDictionary
            println(parsedResult)
            if let tweets = parsedResult["statuses"] as? NSDictionary {
               for tweetsDict in tweets {
                   let title = tweetsDict["text"] as NSString
                   println("text: \(title)")
                   let coordinates = tweetsDict["coordinates"]
                   println("coordinates: \(coordinates)\n")
               }
            }else {
                   println("Error: \(connectionError)")
             }

         }
```

My code runs till println(parsedResult) as I'm getting a valid response from the twitter api. However I'm having trouble extracting the tweet text from the JSON response.

Comment: Did you need to authenticate before this? I'm getting error : Bad Authentication data. (code 215)})

Comment: I just want to query for $AAPL for example. I don't want to post or view users timeline. I should be able to do that with Fabric without making user login or anything right?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `Fabric`, you can create tweet objects from the response using `TWTRTweet` method

```
+ (NSArray *)tweetsWithJSONArray:(NSArray *)array;
```

It creates an array of `TWTRTweet` instances from the array of Twitter API JSON response.

```
NSArray *tweetData = [TWTRTweet tweetsWithJSONArray:responseFromTwitter];
[tableview  reloadData];
```

You can use tweet objects to populate in tableview in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. To return a tweet cell,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *cellID = @"TweetCell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

        TWTRTweet *tweet = twitterResponse[indexPath.row];
        [(TWTRTweetTableViewCell *)cell configureWithTweet:tweet];

    return cell;
}
```

**EDIT**

In **Swift**, you can do as:

```
// Create an array of tweet model objects from a JSON array
tweetData = TWTRTweet.tweetsWithJSONArray(responseFromTwitter)
tableView.reloadData()

//create Tweet cells

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let tweet = tweetData[indexPath.row]
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(tweetTableReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as TWTRTweetTableViewCell
      cell.configureWithTweet(tweet)

      return cell
  }
```

Hope it helps!

[Reference taken from here](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/show-tweets)

Comment: Hi! Not familiar with Objective C at all since I am beginner to iOS Development and started using Swift. Can you explain with help of swift code?

Comment: This could work but is limited in functionality. i.e. you can't reload older tweets without making your own Controller class. I would suggest TWTRTimelineViewController. Though its not perfect and I have opened a few issues against it here: https://twittercommunity.com/t/6-twtrtimelineviewcontroller-issues/51534

Answer (score 0):

There is a little error with you code 
Use this code it work best for me , set this code in certain function on button action

```
 Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.sendTwitterRequest(request) {
                    (response, data, connectionError) -> Void in
        if (connectionError == nil) {
            var jsonError : NSError?
            let parsedResult  =
            NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,
                            options: nil,
                            error: &jsonError) as NSDictionary
            println(parsedResult)
            if let tweets = parsedResult["status"] as? NSDictionary {
                 println(tweets)
               for tweetsDict in tweets {
                   let title = tweetsDict["text"] as NSString
                   println("text: \(title)")
                   let coordinates = tweetsDict["coordinates"]
                   println("coordinates: \(coordinates)\n")
               }
            }else {
                   println("Error: \(connectionError)")
             }

         }
```

Comment: Hi! Can you point out the error in my code? I need to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: to share and to post tweet you first have to start the Twitter session so that the application confirms that user is login

Comment: I'm already doing that. I have a anonymous session and that happens in different part of the code. I'm getting a valid response from the twitter api and the code runs till println(parsedResult). It's however parsing the json for text and coordinates that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: it does not execute the IF Statement then check for the Key values spelling are they correct  for evey Key as these are wrong"statuses" use the correct spellings and then tell me ... else i will find other solution

Comment: kindly post the json which you get .... you are storing it in Dictionary .. it must be stored in Array first depends on the Json ..

Comment: yes. The returned JSON is a dictionary. Not an array. And statuses is the correct keyword. Here's a sample response - http://pastebin.com/nkumqu3b . Some data looks garbled because of copy pasting but the overall structure is intact.